# filtering XML nodes containing a greater-than character in node text

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have a LINQ query from an XML file.  I am filtering out certain nodes that have empty children, but also wanted to filter nodes which contain illegal characters.

From the example below, you can see that I am attempting to filter nodes that also have a greater-than character `<` in them.  (See child3 in XML sample)

However, this does not work.  I can test for other characters inside the node like `*` but `<` does not work.

How can I modify my LINQ query to check for a greater-than character `<` inside a node.

```
<Root>
   <Header>
        <total>123456</total>
    </Header>
    <Transactions>
      <Txn>
         <child1>BSmith</value1>
         <child2>Bob Smith</child2>
         <child3>Acme Company<</child3>
         <child4>Suite 3B</child4>
         <child5>1234 Main Street</child5>
      </Txn>
      ...
    </Transactions>
</Root>

var root = XElement.Parse(xmlText);                
var elementsThatCanBeEmpty = new HashSet<XName>
{
    XName.Get("child4")
};

var transactionList = from transactions in 
                      root.Elements(XName.Get("Transactions"))
                      .Elements().AsEnumerable()
                      where transactions.Elements().Any
                      (
                        el =>
                        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Value) || el.Value.Contains("*")) &&
                        !elementsThatCanBeEmpty.Contains(el.Name)
                      )
                      select new 
                      { 
                         UserName = transactions.Element(XName.Get("child1")).Value
                      };
```

Comment: Doesn't that < in the file make it illegal - that is, not valid xml? It should be encoded. If it is encoded, you should be able to look for the encoded value.

Comment: The XML you posted is simply not valid, so the first line of your code should throw an exception and you can't use LINQ to XML to with a “XML” such as this.

Comment: @schroedingers-cat, now that you mention it, yes, it would be illegal. a third party company sends us this xml file and i am checking for inconsistencies and empty nodes in the file. It just so happens that the end user can input a < inside a field. then when the XML file is generated, we get it with the < inside the node.

Comment: Then I would suggest the first stage is to verify that the XML is valid before trying to use XML tools on it.

Comment: @Nick, if user enters `<`, the correct thing would be to encode it (as `&lt;`) and I think any XML library will do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this. it is a very good starting point for you and you can use WHERE keyword to filter your XML data

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing